# http 500 error trying to PDO:bindParam

Tags: php, pdo, http-status-code-500, bindparam

I am trying to create a register form. Having it sucessfully executed in my localhost (XAMPP), I uploaded it to a webserver(000webhost). But when I ran the file, the browser gave me a 500 http error.

I tried to debug the code, and figured out that the php file stopped executing at my PDO bindParam() function

```
$prep_stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (`UserID`, `Username`, `Password`, `FullName`, `Role`, `Gender`, `Age`, `DoB`, `Email`, `Phonenumber` , `RegDate`, `Intro`, `E_isVerified`, `TrustPoint`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, 0, 0);");

$prep_stmt->bind_Param("sssiiisssss", $reg_user, $reg_password, $reg_fullname, $reg_role, $reg_gender, $reg_age, $date, $reg_email, $reg_phone,  $reg_date, $reg_desc);
```

It didn't execute any other lines after the bind_Param function(), and return a HTTP ERROR 500

Here's my full code

```
<?php

    function validateTime($date, $format = 'Y-m-d'){
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
    }

    require('connect.php');

    $prep_stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (`UserID`, `Username`, `Password`, `FullName`, `Role`, `Gender`, `Age`, `DoB`, `Email`, `Phonenumber` , `RegDate`, `Intro`, `E_isVerified`, `TrustPoint`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, 0, 0);");

    $prep_stmt->bind_Param("sssiiisssss", $reg_user, $reg_password, $reg_fullname, $reg_role, $reg_gender, $reg_age, $date, $reg_email, $reg_phone,  $reg_date, $reg_desc);

    $token = "";
    $reg_age = 10;  //Remember to add it later

    $reg_user = $_POST['username'];
    $reg_user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_user);

    $reg_password = $_POST['password'];
    $reg_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_password);

    $reg_fullname = $_POST['name'];
    $reg_fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_fullname);

    $reg_cfpassword = $_POST['cf_password'];
    $reg_cfpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_cfpassword);

    $reg_phone = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $reg_phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_phone);

    $reg_email = $_POST['email'];
    $reg_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_email);

    $day = $_POST['dd'];
    $day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $day);

    $month = $_POST['mm'];
    $month = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $month);

    $year = $_POST['yyyy'];
    $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $year);


    $reg_gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $reg_gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_gender);

    $reg_country = $_POST['country'];
    $reg_country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_country);

    $reg_city = $_POST['city'];
    $reg_city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_city);

    $reg_address = $_POST['address'];
    $reg_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_address);

    $reg_role = $_POST['role'];
    $reg_role = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_role);

    $reg_brandname = $_POST['brandname'];
    $reg_brandname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_brandname);

    $reg_job = $_POST['job'];
    $reg_job = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_job);

    $reg_desc = $_POST['description'];
    $reb_desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_desc);

    $reg_agree = $_POST['agree'];
    $reg_agree = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_agree);

    $reg_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $reg_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $reg_date);

    //Check

    $name_check = "/^.{1,100}$/";
    $password_check = "/^.{1,100}$/"; //Check if password == confirm
    if ($reg_password != $reg_cfpassword){
        header("Location: register.php?err=1");
        exit;

    }
    $phonenumber_check = "/^[0]{1}[0-9]{9,10}$/";
    $username_check = "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{3,50}$/"; //Unique
    //Date check
    $date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
    // echo $date;


    // if (!validateTime($date)) $token.="&date=1";

    if (!preg_match($name_check, $reg_fullname)) $token.="&name=1";
    if (!preg_match($password_check,$reg_password)) $token.="&pw=1";
    if (!preg_match($phonenumber_check, $reg_phone)) $token.="&phone=1";
    if (!preg_match($username_check, $reg_user)) $token.="&usr=1";


    $querycheck = "SELECT Username FROM user WHERE Username='$reg_user'";
    $res = $conn->query($querycheck);

    if ($res->num_rows > 0){
        $token.="&usr_dup=1";
        }

    if ($token == "" && $prep_stmt->execute()){
        $track_id_query = "SELECT `UserID`,`Username`,`Password` FROM `user` WHERE Username = '$reg_user'";
        $track_id_result = mysqli_query($conn, $track_id_query);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($track_id_result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            session_start();
            $cookie_username = 'username';
            $cookie_id = 'id';
            $cookie_password = 'password';
            $username = $row['Username'];
            $password = $row['Password'];
            $id = $row['UserID'];
            // set cookies
            setcookie($cookie_username, $username, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
            setcookie($cookie_id, $id, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
            setcookie($cookie_password, $password, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $prep_stmt->close();

            $path = "images/users/".$id;
            mkdir($path, 0700);
            fopen($path."/avatar.png","w");
            copy('images/blank.jpgo',$path."/avatar.jpg");
            header('Location: account.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
    else {
        // die(mysqli_error($conn));
        header('Location: register.php?'.$token);
        exit;
    }
    // die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Please extract a minimal example (MCVE), as per site guidelines.

Comment: What does the error say? Also you do not have to escape strings when using prepared/parameterized queries so you can clean up your code quite a bit.

Comment: This page isn’t working
fauxpas.cf is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: you've set role and gender as an int? Is that right?

Comment: I'm really confused. Something must be wrong with my prepared statement query, I just don't know where.

Comment: @Juakali92 I did

Comment: Just reminding, there's NO problem when I executed it in my localhost.

Comment: Also, it did ran normally on the webserver when I used mysqli_query()

Comment: Thats just the "pretty" error shown to visitors. You need to check the server error log to see the error message

Comment: At last I figured out that the error lies on my database. There is a missing column that I previously added in my local database. Everything is OK now. Thanks all for your help!